# How to be safely install light bulb for outdoor vegetable?

Tags: vegetables, bulbs, sunlight, light

My patio does not have direct sunlight, but I want to build a hydroponic system. The vegetable that I want to plant requires a lot of light, so I also want to put lighting system outdoor for the vegetable. Does any product in the market do the task?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to lighting, you could probably get away with any type of fluorescent light but really, you want to be looking for a full spectrum light system as it comes the closest to natural light (it's right around 94% of the solar spectrum).

You want the lights to be within a few inches of your plants as well or your plants will get too leggy so incandescent bulbs aren't a great choice as they give off too much heat and will burn your plants.

One last thing to note is the time the light is on. You want to maintain 14-16 hours of lighting with a rest period so you'll want to get some sort of timer.

Comment: Does any grow light system not afraid raining?